# c# Error: Unexpected token DictionaryEnd before 867086

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Estoy intentando mostrar por pantalla un pdf que he escaneado y guardado en una base de datos. Funciona bien, pero el archivo es muy grande y quiero comprimirlo.

Uso Visual Studio 2019 y el código que he usado para obtener la imagen es el siguiente:

```
private static void ObtenerImagen(ImageFile image, PdfDocument doc, string contPlaca, string contNumPropuesta)
{
   byte[] imagenEnBytes = image.FileData.get_BinaryData();
   MemoryStream ms = new(imagenEnBytes);

   MemoryStream stream = new();
   Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
   XImage imagen = XImage.FromStream(ms);

   PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();
   page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
   XGraphics graficos = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
   graficos.DrawImage(imagen, 0, 0);
   doc.Save(stream, false);
   byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();

   MessageBox.Show("Bytes: " + bytes.Length.ToString());

   if (bytes.Length/1024 > 500)
   {
      //código que debo usar
   }
   
   DataTable dt = new();
   SqlCommand anadir = new(actualizar, con);
   param.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contPlaca", contenidoPlaca);
   param.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contNumPropuesta", contenidoNumeroPropuesta);
   anadir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@documento", bytes);
   con.Open();
   anadir.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();

   byte[] ap = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["documento"];
   MemoryStream ms = new(ap);
   pdfDocumentView1.Visible = true;
   pdfDocumentView1.Load(ms);
}
```

He intentado añadir esto dentro del if, pero me da un error:

```
   stream = new();
   doc.Pages.Remove(page);
   img = Image.FromStream(ms);
   img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   imagen = XImage.FromStream(stream);
   
   page = doc.AddPage();
   page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
   graficos = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
   graficos.DrawImage(imagen, 0, 0);
   doc.Save(stream, false);
   bytes = stream.ToArray();
   MessageBox.Show("Bytes at the end: " + bytes.Length.ToString());
```

```
Syncfusion.Pdf.PdfException: Unexpected token DictionaryEnd before 861431
   at Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing.PdfLoadedDocument.LoadDocument(Stream file)
   at Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing.PdfLoadedDocument..ctor(Stream file)
   at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.PdfViewer.PdfDocumentView.Load(Stream stream)
   at GestionDocumental.VentanaGestionDocumental.MostrarDoc(DataTable dt) in C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\GestionDocumental\VentanaGestionDocumental.cs:line 225
```

Quiero que el archivo no supere los 500KB, por lo que, si los supera, entra en el `if`. De la forma que he intentado, creo que las líneas que no funcionan son las siguientes, y que por ello no se guarda bien en la base de datos.

```
img = Image.FromStream(ms);
img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
imagen = XImage.FromStream(stream);
```

EDICIÓN: También he intentado hacerlo con un `Bitmap`, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error o muestra el pdf aumentado:

```
Bitmap bm = new(img, new Size((int)(img.Width * 0.50), (int)(img.Height * 0.50)));
bm.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
imagen = XImage.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: @gbianchi el error me da en esta línea ```pdfDocumentView1.Load(ms);```. ¿A qué te refieres con el error como texto?

Comment: @gbianchi Ahora he conseguido que lo muestre, pero en vez de disminuir el tamaño del pdf lo aumenta

Comment: debes tener un error completo mas alla de lo que mostras en el titulo no? en que linea? en que momento? pone el error completo....

Comment: Y en otra pregunta te comente que no todo formato es comprimible...

Comment: @gbianchi ya no me sale ningún error, ahora es solo lo del tamaño